# MediaPlayer stops when changing SystemClock.setCurrentTimeMillis(millis)

Tags: android

So I have an app that plays a video.
And I have a time sync server for setting the datetime of the device. It seems that whenever I call `SystemClock.setCurrentTimeMillis(millis)` the video stops.

I am using `android.media.MediaPlayer.MediaPlayer()` object to play the video?
Has anyone else experienced this? I was planning on creating a watchdog thread that just monitors the current duration. But just wanted to know if anyone had come across this already?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I came across the same situation on some devices. Probably hardware libs use the system time clock in the in decoding or av sync implementation; it happens. Only solution on those devices was to stop/restart the MediaPlayer. But it probably depends on the implementation of the lower levels.

Comment: It seems we only have problems with mpeg 4, MediaPlayer works with mpeg-1/2 videos.